# Exibir valor do input selecionado

Tags: jquery

Eu tenho dois inputs com seus respectivos ID's, eu gostaria que no alert seja exibido o valor inserido no campo selecionado, então se eu estiver digitando no campo 1 será exibido o valor no alert referente ao campo 1, se eu estiver digitando no campo 2 seja exibido o valor no alert referente ao campo 2.

Atualização Idéia

Eu vi o código do JuniorNunes7 e tive uma idéia e gostaria de fazer uma coisa nova, me desculpem. Veja a imagem:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Obrigado

Comment: Estou votando para fechar esta pergunta como fora de escopo porque a pergunta inicial era outra coisa, agora as respostas não fazem mais sentido

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Creio que seja isso que você precisa segundo a descrição da sua imagem, só não coloquei nenhum alerta, mas imagino que estava querendo apenas para testar...

```js
$("#principal").on('change keyup paste', function(){
  var input = $('.check:checked').val();
  $("#"+input).val($(this).val());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div>
  <label>Master</label>
  <input id="principal" type="text">
</div>
<br />

<div>
  <input type="radio" name="check" class="check" value="campo1" checked>
  <label>campo1</label>
  <input class="campo" id="campo1" name="campo1" type="text" readonly>
</div>

<div>
  <input type="radio" name="check" class="check" value="campo2">
  <label>campo2</label>
  <input class="campo" id="campo2" name="campo2" type="text" readonly>
</div>
```

Comment: Obrigado pelas dicas.

Answer (score 1):

Pra mostrar algo sempre que o valor do *input* for alterado (digitado, apagado, colado), você pode usar o evento `onInput`.

```
$('#input-id').on('input', function() {
    alert($(this).val());
});
```

Também é possível usar o `change`, ele será disparado só quando o usuário "deselecionar" o input.

```
$('#input-id').on('change', function() {
    alert($(this).val());
});
```

[Veja um exemplo funcional no JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/w4bdn54z/6)